# Generating a calibration plot from Tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, tidymodels, calibration

I have used Tidymodel to build a logistic regression model.
While I can extract the performance metrics, I would like to plot the agreement between predictions and observations (calibration plot)

But, have yet to find a method to do this - has anyone got experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

tidymodels does not have a calibration plot function yet (I'm literally working on that now). I would suggest using the one in [`caret`](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html#calib). I don't expect our work to be ready for a while.

Comment: Thank you, good luck with the developing - I look forward to seeing the outputs